# get last part of a string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to get the last substring of a variable (the last part after the underscore), in this case: "myvar".

```
x = "string__subvar1__subvar2__subvar3__myvar"
```

my attempts result in a match starting from the first substring, e.g.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "__.*?$)
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: What about this `tail(strsplit(x, '__', fixed = T)[[1]], 1)`?

Comment: yes, this works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
sub('.*\\__', '', x)
```

Comment: this produces `"subvar2_subvar3_myvar"` instead of `myvar`.

Comment: just ran it again, produces myvar

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x,"[a-zA-Z]+$")
```

**EDIT**:
 one could use lookaround feature as well: `str_extract(x,"(?=_*)[a-zA-Z]+$")`

also from  baseR

```
regmatches(x,gregexpr("[a-zA-Z]+$",x))[[1]]
```

From documentation `?regex`:

> The caret ^ and the dollar sign $ are metacharacters that respectively
>   match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line.

Comment: If the end of the string could also be something like "subvar4" this approach would need a little modification, right?

Comment: When I modify the search string as `y = "string__subvar1__subvar2_subvar3_myvar"` the result is also "myvar" - but in this case it has not split on the "__" string.

Comment: `str_extract(x,"(?=_*)[a-zA-Z]+$")` what about this, @Henk sorry brother, I never got from your question that you need split via _ (underscore)

Comment: No worries, I should have made this clearer and edited the question. This code works.

Answer (score 1):

Could this work? Sorry, I hope i'm understanding what you're asking correctly.

```
substr(x,gregexpr("_",x)[[1]][length(gregexpr("_",x)[[1]])]+1,nchar(x))
[1] "myvar"
```

Comment: Yes, you understood exactly right. It works...I just wished this was a little easier.